# Outputting specific lines based on date and time

Tags: unix, logging, sed, awk, grep

I'm very noob at Linux and I'm trying to figure out a way to automate my data mining process for work since there are so many values that I need to sort through. I currently have a log file that is in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
Sensor0 Temperature (Equation 1) is <Value0> Celsius
Sensor1 Temperature (Equation 1) is <Value1> Celsius
Sensor2 Temperature (Equation 1) is <Value2> Celsius
Sensor3 Temperature (Equation 1) is <Value3> Celsius
```

The program spits out these values in this format every 5 seconds. What I really want to do is to find a way to process this log file and into another log file that has ONLY the 4 Sensor values that I need based on the date and time.

Currently, I am able to process the file into the following format by filtering phrases out using `sed`.

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS 
<Value0>
<Value1>
<Value2>
<Value3>
```

How do I output those 4 values by searching the specific date and time? I have a separate log file that has all the time stamps of the corner cycles that I ran, which I am using as a reference in my search of the temperature values. The format of that file is:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

In the final processed output, I want the contents to display the following using the corner specified time stamps:

```
Date, Time, Sensor0, Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3
YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MM:SS, <Value0>, <Value1>, <Value2>, <Value3>
```

Comment: Your posted sample input file only contains one date/time so what do you mean when you say `searching the specific date and time`? Is that across multiple input files or does your one input file really contain multiple date/time stamps? If the latter update your question to show some more truly representative input.

Comment: The output loops and appends itself every 5 seconds in that format. I want to be able to reference to another log file that will automatically search for all the matching time stamps with the 4 temperature values and pipe it to separate log file.

Answer (score 0):

if you for exemple want all event at 00:00:00 for july 2013:

```bash
egrep "2013-07-.. 00:00:00" -A 4 /var/log/temp.log
```

that looks for all lines matching "2013-07-.. 00:00:00", in file /var/log/temp.log, and also include the next 4 lines (-A 4) in the output